# python3でSQL文"SELECT count (*)" 実行時に数字のみの結果を受け取りたい

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

Python3のコードの中で、データベースのテーブルの要素数を取得する際に、数字のみの結果を受け取りたいです。

例えば、

```
"SELECT count (*) FROM sampleDB;"
```

のSQLを使用した場合、結果は、

```
[(10,)]
```

のように、リストとタプルの形での値の取得となりますが、

```
"[ ]"、"( )"、","
```

が付かず、

```
10
```

のように、数字のみの結果を取得する方法はありますでしょうか？

それとも、結果取得後に自分で、必要のない記号等をなくすしか方法はないでしょうか？

ご教授のほどよろしくお願いします。

環境：
・PostgreSQL
・Psycopg2

【追記】実行コード

```
conText = "host={} port={} dbname={} user={} password={}"
        conText = conText.format(PATH, PORT, DBNAME, USER, PASSWORD)

connection = psycopg2.connect(conText)
        cur = connection.cursor()

        sql = "SELECT count (*) FROM sampleDB;"

        cur.execute(sql)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        connection.close()

        print(rows) # [(10,)]
```

Comment: データベースエンジンは何を使っていますか？どのようなクライアント（ツール）を用いてアクセスしていますか？それによって回答が変わると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。・PostgreSQL・Psycopg2を利用しています。

Comment: 実行したコードを質問に追記してもらえますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。質問欄にコードを追記しました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**【質問に対する直接の回答】**

> それとも、結果取得後に自分で、必要のない記号等をなくすしか方法はないでしょうか？

はい、そうです。
`cur.fetchall()`はm個の列(タプル)のn行(リスト)を返します。
今回のSQLは１行１列を返しますが、`select`の結果がただ一つかどうかは`fetchall()`には分かりません。

```
rows[0][0]
```

で`count (*)`の結果を得ることができます。

**【気になったこと】**
質問された方は`"[ ]"、"( )"、","`をデータに含まれる文字と認識されているようですが、
これらの記号はタプルやリストなどデータの構造を表現しているだけです。
これらの記号をなくすのではなく、データの構造(リストやタプル)に見合った方法でデータを取得すれば所望の結果を得られます。

Comment: ご返答いただきありがとうございます。m個の列(タプル)のn行(リスト)を返すというですので、DBデータを取得後に自分で調整します。データのIndexを指定する方法で対応しようと思います。